# How to get the authentication in any class/service in spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

We are running a Spring-Boot application using spring-security for authentication.
I need to access the authentication token in a Aspect filter class to populate the `UserDetails` object with the access resources.
How can I get it?

Tried below but getting `null` value.

```
String token =(String)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Comment: This line should work. Are you sure you aspect is called after authentication?

Comment: Maybe `principal` is null, but `authentication` is not null. Try to check it.

Comment: can't typecast authentication to string